# Is "thru" for "through" acceptable? "Tho" for "though"?

Tags: american-english, spelling

I've been told that in American English, sometimes words ending in *-ough* are written *-u*: for example *thru* instead of *through*.

Is this correct English, or is it simply a common error?
If it is correct, what are the rules for this spelling?

Comment: There's another *-ough* class that wouldn't be shortened to *-u* -- place names ending in *-borough*, often shortened to *-boro*.  (It's amusing to see at times, by the side of the road, adjacent signs with the different spellings; one such pair is in North Attleboro/o, Massachusetts.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

"Thru" is correct (however very informal, not a very good idea, and only used when space is at a real premium — e.g. road signs, technical drawings) English, but *-u* is not a shortened way of *-ough* except in words that derivate from *through* (e.g. *breakthrough*).

From memory, I can recall *although*, *enough* etc. where *-ough* can't be replaced by *-u* (*althu*, *enu* etc.), since in those words *-ough* doesn't have a /u/ sound. (However, *although* can be shortened to *altho*, as noted in a comment — however, [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/altho) and [other dictionaries](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/altho?s=t) register it, noting that it's quite informal.)

Comment: N.b.: Merriam-Webster calls it an "informal simplification" so it should be avoided in any formal writing. I would only ever use it for texts.

Comment: +1 The reason why *though* and *enough* can't be written **thu* and **enu* is obviously that they are not pronounced /u/, unlike through. I can't think of any other very common words ending on *-ough* and pronounced -/u/. // You might want to stress a little more that spelling *thru* is a really bad idea nearly everywhere, including most of the Internet, e-mails, school, etc. People may think, "oh, I'm not writing to my professor, so it's informal", whereas "informal" in linguistics is sometimes a bit of a euphemism for what others call "bad spelling, ignorant, wrong", as it is in this case.

Comment: "Although" is shortened to "altho."

Comment: To piggy-back on what @Cerberus said, even tho you can't substitute a -u for words like _rough_ or _tough_, you still can use a very similar phonetic shorthand, like [_ruff and tuff_](http://www.ruffandtuff.net/contact.php). Again, though, this kind of shorthand can work well for gimmicky marketing purposes, but should be avoided in more formal contexts.

Comment: I've never seen *altho*. Bad recommendation. VERY informal, only for internet chat, I would say.

Comment: No, I’m afraid this is the wrong answer: *thru* is ***not*** an admissible substitute for *through* in Standard English.

Answer (score 23):

As a speaker of American English, I would understand what was meant by *thru* for *through*, but I would find it very informal. The Oxford Dictionary [entry](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thru) supports this, saying that it is:

> chiefly North American; informal spelling of through.

The rule, however, isn't that words ending in *-ough* are shortened to *-u*, but instead in very informal writing the last vowel sound of a word is used instead of the proper ending. This gives *through → thru* because of the final "oo" sound, but also abbreviated forms *though → tho* or *although → altho* because they end in "oh" (as in "cold").

Answer (score 5):

Shortenings you are more or less likely to see for "-ough" (most are, as previously noted, considered at best very informal and at worst a severe case of bad spelling):

1. *through, breakthrough* → u
2. *cough* → off
3. *enough* → uf
4. *tough, rough, slough* (verb) → uff
5. *slough* (noun) → ew/ue
6. *borough, though, although, thorough* → o
7. *furlough* → ow (as in "low")
8. *plough* → ow  (as in "how"; "plow" is now the common spelling)
9. *hiccough* → up  ("hiccup" is now the common spelling)

A couple of "ough" words are never shortened due to either the word's low frequency, variability of pronunciation, or to any replacement being a collision with another word:
*sough, dough, brough, bough, trough*.

Answer (score 4):

*Thru* is a very informal spelling that is never used in print or school. *Through* is probably not the best way to spell it in textspeak, because textspeak avoids long traditional spellings.

But in formal and semi-formal (anything but the most informal) you should avoid using such simplifications unless you are in a place where you've seen others use it. For example, if you use *thru* here at ELL, it won't be considered a misspelling but will definitely be considered too informal.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that "thru" is a valid (and indeed, common) spelling *only* in American English. In British English it is an incorrect spelling, and students in Britain would expect to lose marks in exams for using it.

Comment: Students in America would have similar expectations, at least in my experience.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "valid" and "incorrect" here. [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/thru) has this note: _an informal way of writing 'through'. This is sometimes used in newspapers and very informal American writing, but it is not generally accepted in British English._ In other words, U.S. teachers wouldn't consider this variant a correct way to spell it on a test, either, even if one might see it on a [street sign](http://images.fineartamerica.com/images-small/1-no-thru-way-sign-street-road-random-danielle-mcneil.jpg).

Comment: By invalid, I mean that students writing "thru" for "through" in England is not normal shorthand, and would be considered a form of illiteracy in British English, rather than an acceptable abbreviation in American English; the only exceptions being for "texting" (where artificial abbreviations reign supreme) or in imported phrases such as a "Drive-Thru".

Comment: It is not admissible in American writing, either, and more than *lite* is.

Comment: But *thru* and *lite* are very common in American corporate branding. Using these forms in British English only occurs when one is trying to affect an Americanism or make fun of that habit.